# uWSGI cannot find python module

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

I have a python application (Django + nginx + uWSGI) running on cloud server.

But I failed to start uWSGI when I typed,

```
 sudo uwsgi --uid www-data --gid www-data --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals
```

Here is log of uWSGI file. (uwsgi.mySite.log)

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.3 (32bit) on [Wed Apr  2 00:43:45 2014] ***
compiled with version: 4.6.3 on 02 April 2014 00:40:56
os: Linux-3.2.0-34-generic-pae #53-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 15 11:11:12 UTC 2012
nodename: eb9c1026-428e-43d4-b7fc-ee92761848bd
machine: i686
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /etc/uwsgi/vassals
writing pidfile to /var/www/mySiteDomain/logs/uwsgi.mySite.pid
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
your processes number limit is 7683
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
 *** WARNING: you have enabled harakiri without post buffering. Slow upload could be             rejected on post-unbuffered webservers ***
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
VirtualHosting mode enabled.
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /dev/shm/mySite.sock fd 3
Python version: 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 20:11:37)  [GCC 4.6.3]
Set PythonHome to /root/.virtualenvs/mySite
ImportError: No module named site
VACUUM: pidfile removed.
VACUUM: unix socket /dev/shm/mySite.sock removed.
```

It seems to be uWSGI cannot find python module.

nginx have no problem.

Here is my uWSGI ini file.

```
[uwsgi]
## variables
username            = root
projectname         = mySite
projectdomain       = mySiteDomain
base                = /var/www/%(projectdomain)
## config
uid                 = www-data
gid                 = www-data
vhost               = true
# master
master              = true
# maximum number of processes
processes           = 10
# respawn processes taking more than 20 seconds
harakiri            = 20
# the socket (use the full path to be safe)
socket              = /dev/shm/%(projectname).sock
# with appropriate permissions - *may* be needed
chmod-socket        = 775
enable-threads      = true
# the base directory
chdir               = %(base)
# Django's wsgi file
module              = %(projectname).wsgi
# the virtualenv
home                = /%(username)/.virtualenvs/%(projectname)
# clear environment on exit
vacuum              = true
max-request         = 5000
daemonize           = %(base)/logs/uwsgi.%(projectname).log
pidfile             = %(base)/logs/uwsgi.%(projectname).pid
```

I checked that "site.py" is located at /root/.virtualenvs/mySite/lib/python2.7

I've also tried to change home(in uWSGI ini file) as "/%(username)/.virtualenvs/%(projectname)/lib/python2.7", but I got same error.

Virtualenv's sys.path also includes these python paths.

I don't know what is wrong. Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: I've deleted my answer. I checked the documentation for uwsgi and found that `virtualenv` is an alias for `home`. I did not know that. Oops!

Comment: The problem was that I installed uWSGI as a linux package, not the python package. In other words, "pip install uWSGI" is right and "apt-get install uWSGI" is wrong.

Comment: You can certainly shoot yourself in the foot with that. However, I run Debian testing and the way I install uwsgi in production is to do `apt-get install uwsgi` *and* then `pip install uwsgi`. :) Then I symlink `/usr/bin/uwsgi` to `/usr/local/bin/uwsgi`. This way `uswgi` is installed as a proper service.

Comment: Oh, you're right. The real problem was that the uWSGI wasn't served on a local.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about configuration, not programming.